# how to find out how a ios native function works when documentation is missing

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

I'm currently studying cocurrency in ios and I want to know how the type function `class func global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass)` works.

I have visited the [offical apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) on the method, but was appalled to find that there is no comments or documentation of any kind on the page.

So I was just wondering, how to find out how a method works in situations like this? How do apple expect developers to work when no basic documentation is provided?

Comment: You can have a look at the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: @Alladinian Thanks for pointing it out, i'm going through it right now. I'm just frustrated that a basic function like this does not have any documentations at all. I guess the world is not perfect and we just have to deal with it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the function you describe is not an iOS sdk function but just basic Swift functionality you can look it up as Swift is opensource:

https://github.com/apple/swift/

or more the specific function you asked for:
https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/adc54c8a4d13fbebfeb68244bac401ef2528d6d0/stdlib/public/SDK/Dispatch

Comment: hi simon, thanks for pointing out the source code! Without any documentation, the source code is definitely the next best thing available. Appreciate you helping out! :)